# How to use spring batch to parse fixed length formats Files (File Without any delimiter)

Tags: spring, spring-batch

how to Configure spring-batch reader for fixed length formats Files (File Without any delimiter).

Each element is determined in relation to its starting and ending position.

**Sample of line :**

120180208FAILED
220180208SUCCES
120170208SUCCES
1 : code ,  20180208 : date ,FAILED : status

Comment: I have found the answer  here https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html  (with FixedLengthTokenizer)
Thinks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use **FixedLengthTokenizer** reader for this.

This is how you can configure `FixedLengthTokenizer` .

> Sample Text file
>
> UK21341EAH4121131.11customer1
> UK21341EAH4221232.11customer2
> UK21341EAH4321333.11customer3
> UK21341EAH4421434.11customer4
> UK21341EAH4521535.11customer5

**Java Config**

```
@Bean
    public FixedLengthTokenizer fixedLengthTokenizer() {
            FixedLengthTokenizer tokenizer = new FixedLengthTokenizer();
    
            tokenizer.setNames("ISIN", "Quantity", "Price", "Customer");
            tokenizer.setColumns(new Range(1,12),
                                 new Range(13,15),
                                 new Range(16,20),
                                 new Range(21,29));
            return tokenizer;
    }
```

**XML Config**

```
<bean id="fixedLengthLineTokenizer"
      class="org.springframework.batch.io.file.transform.FixedLengthTokenizer">
    <property name="names" value="ISIN,Quantity,Price,Customer" />
    <property name="columns" value="1-12, 13-15, 16-20, 21-29" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Needs to be new Range(1,12)  instead of new Range(1-12)

Answer (score 0):

When configuring the FixedLengthLineTokenizer, each of these lengths must be provided in the form of ranges:

```
<bean id="fixedLengthLineTokenizer"
      class="org.springframework.batch.io.file.transform.FixedLengthTokenizer">
    <property name="names" value="ISIN,Quantity,Price,Customer" />
    <property name="columns" value="1-12, 13-15, 16-20, 21-29" />
</bean>
```

visit https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#fixedLengthFileFormats