# Process cobol flat feed file (with different format) using spring batch

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I am trying to use spring batch to consume data generated by a cobol program. Lets assume the below is the data.

```
CBMWM3    COU**********EA40176
CBMWM5    CON**********G114738
SMERGLS4507BLU**********F231353
TFORF150  5*******G539501
```

There are three different formats in the file based on the first character.

```
C - MAKE, MODEL, CLASSIFICATION, VIN
S - MAKE, MODEL, PASS CAPACITY, COLOR, VIN
T - MAKE, MODEL, PASS CAPACITY, VIN
```

I would like to use a FlatFileItemReader and it works best for a single format. How can I update the code to process different formats on the same file ? 
I am using Spring boot for this batch job.

Edit 1:

```
@Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<CarDetails> reader() {
        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<CarDetails>()
                .name("carDetailsReader")
                .resource(new FileSystemResource("/path/to/inputFile"))
                .fixedLength()
                    .addColumns(new Range(1))

                    /* Format for lines starting with C
                    .addColumns(new Range(2,4))
                    .addColumns(new Range(5,9))
                    .addColumns(new Range(10,12))
                    .addColumns(new Range(13,29)) */

                    /* Format for lines starting with S
                    .addColumns(new Range(2,4))
                    .addColumns(new Range(5,9))
                    .addColumns(new Range(9,10))
                    .addColumns(new Range(11,13))
                    .addColumns(new Range(14,30)) */

                    /* Format for lines starting with T
                    .addColumns(new Range(2,4))
                    .addColumns(new Range(5,9))
                    .addColumns(new Range(9,10))
                    .addColumns(new Range(11,26)) * /

                 // Looks like I cant have all three formats here. 

                .names(new String[]{"Char", "make", "model", "Clasification", "VIN"})
                // Need some facility to accept multiple formats in names too. 

                .fieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>() {{
                    setTargetType(CarDetails.class);
                }})
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: What is the issue/problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to create a batch process and It works fine for one format. However I would have to modify the reader() to accept different formats.... Some thing like the edit I made to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/file/mapping/PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper.html) is what you are looking for. It allows you to match lines based on a pattern and tokenize/map each line type to the corresponding domain type.

You can find an example of how to use it [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/a7092a21e428cf904f210aff2682b518dc3649c5/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/item/file/mapping/PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapperTests.java).

Comment: Thanks much. This looks great !

Comment: I found I also needed FixedLengthTokenizers in many situations.  A useful code snippet is here: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48773303/how-to-use-spring-batch-to-parse-fixed-length-formats-files-file-without-any-de